# Highlight particular item on alert dialog in android

Tags: java, android, dialog

I am showing a `list of items` in an alert dialog. I'd like to make some items selected by default(highlight a row) - display `nth` item - when the dialog is shown.

I am a newbie to android and currently i am planning to extend arrayadapter to override getview method to highlight a particular row. But the problem is i am not sure whether my approach is right.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable question. I'd assume you've been downvoted for the lack of effort. You should post what you have so far/what you've tried along with the Log Cat trace if you're experiencing a specific error

Comment: I am a newbie to android and currently i am planning to extend arrayadapter to override getview method to highlight a particular row. But the problem is i am not sure whether my approach is right.

Answer (score 0):

You probably dont need to override the adapter in this case. What you are suggesting will work, however it's cleaner if you have a background selector set for your list then you can mark the items in question as checked and have the selector highlight them. There are some good tutorials on ListViews in the android docs

Comment: Hi Nick, Thanks for the prompt response. Tried a few solutions i got in google, did not work. Can you provide me the link of some tutorial of what you said above ?

Comment: And one more question is that i do not use list view as of now and using 

 fileOpenBuilder.setItems(allFiles,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
 }
 
method to open a dialog with list. Will i be able to set the item color with the current implementation itself or should i need a list view for doing this?